# Query logic using eloquent to search data based on many to many relationship in laravel

Tags: database, laravel, database-design, eloquent, relational-database

I have `guides` and `areas` table they have many to many relationship so i have another table to connect them named `guidings`. quick explanation, in real life a tour guide knows many areas and an area can be known by many tour guide.
i want to search tour guide based on an array of areas that user sends to controller but at the same time the tour guide also must come with information of his area expertise (that he knows) in the view.

the tables like the following:

```
guides
   - id       integer, primary key
   - name     string

areas
   - id       integer, primary key
   - name     string

guidings
   - guide_id integer, foreign key
   - area_id  integer, foreign key
```

I have set up the models like the following:

```php
model guide
   public function guides()
   {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Area', 'guidings', 'guide_id', 'area_id');
   }

model area
   public function users()
   {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'guidings', 'area_id', 'guide_id');
   }
```

my controller looks like this

```php
$areas = [1, 2, 3]; //actually this array i get from request, it based on id of area

$guides = Guide::with('areas')->where('id', '>' , 0);
$countGuide = count(Guide::all());
for ($i=0; $i < $countGuide; $i++) {
     $guides = $guides->orWhere(); //i stuck in here
}
$guides = $guides->get();

return response()->json($guides); //the data will be sent to ajax in view
```

so how can I search tour guide based on an array of areas that user sends to controller but at the same time the tour guide also must come with information of his area expertise (that he knows) in the view.
any suggestion to do? thank you

Comment: and... what is the question ?

Comment: @ijustried how can I search tour guide based on an array of areas that user sends to controller but at the same time the tour guide also must come with information of his area expertise (that he knows) in the view

Comment: Does a guide have to be linked to all of the areas in the array or just one of them?

Comment: @RossWilson all of the areas, think of just displaying all the guide's attribute and all his area but one or all of his areas have to be in array that user send as request

Answer (score 0):

If the guides don't need to match all of the areas then you could have something like:

```
return Guide::with('area')->whereHas('areas', function ($query) use ($areas) {
    $query->whereIn('id', $areas);
})->get();
```

If the guide must match all of the areas then you can use a mixture of `where in` and `having` to accomplish this:

```
$areas = [1, 2, 3];

return Guide::with('area')->whereExists(function ($query) use ($areas) {

    $query->select('guide_id')
        ->from('guidings')
        ->whereRaw('guide_id = guides.id')
        ->whereIn('area_id', $areas)
        ->groupBy('guide_id')
        ->havingRaw("COUNT(DISTINCT area_id) = " . count($areas));

})->get();
```

Also, if you just want to return the guide as JSON then you can simply return the collection from the controller and Laravel will automatically convert it to JSON for you (this same goes for arrays).

Comment: thanks for helping me. it actually works in different way, it finds guides that all of their areas is in $areas array. but instead i want it finds guides that even one of their areas is in $areas array. I mean the guides that come up don't necessarily have to know all the areas that user wants. they will come up even they know only one of the area in $areas array. hope it will make sense.

Comment: @MulqanJunaidi Oh sorry, when I asked you in the comments above if they needed to be linked to all of the areas you said they did. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If there can only be one pivot row for each combination of `guide_id` and `area_id`, you can use this:

```php
$guides = Guide::whereHas('areas', function($query) use($areas) {
    $query->whereIn('areas.id', $productIds);
}, '=', count($areas))->with('areas')->get();
```

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answer?